# Getting process status and exit code from process id in ruby

Tags: ruby, process, pid

I want to create s subprocess in Ruby for running and interacting with other programs, and I need to use `Process.spawn` because `Open3.popen3` does not work in Windows. `Open3.popen3` gives you a nice wait-thread object that allows you to check if the process has finished via `wait_thr.status`, and once it was finished it allows you to get it's exit code via `wait_thr.value.exitstatus`.

`Process.spawn` only gives you the `pid`, so I need a way to get that data from the process id. I've looked at the `Process` and `Kernel` modules and found nothing. `Process::Status` has everything I need, but I can't find any information on how to create one from pid.

How can I tell when the process has finished and what was it's exit status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use the [win32-api gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/win32-api)

You can then use the [GetExitCodeProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from the win32 API.

Comment: I see... well, if I need to add a requirement, I might as well find an Open3 implementation for Windows. I also tried `Process.spawn` on windows and it doesn't work... But thanks anyways!

Comment: Maybe try what's given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593616/spawning-an-independent-thread-or-process-in-ruby)